# What can I make for a Thanksgiving dinner (vegan)?

Tags: recipe-request

What can I make that's vegan for Thanksgiving?

I'm going to a Thanksgiving dinner with family. There will be some vegetarians there, but it will mostly be omnivores. What can I make and bring to share with everyone?

I want to make something that will "blend-in" well with traditional thanksgiving dishes, something *amazing* that I can share with other non-vegetarian attendees to show-off how delicious plant-based meals are, and something that can be filling enough so I'll have plenty to eat -- just in-case there's nothing else there that meets my dietary restrictions..

What's some thanksgiving-style vegan food that I can make this year?

Comment: You've contributed some fantastic content to V&V, so please don't take this the wrong way, but this question is just way too broad to be workable. It falls into the same category as recommendation questions, which every SE site either bans or imposes strict requirements on. Very open-ended and subjective, open to opinions and interpretations. The correctness of potential answers will be hard to judge, and there'd be no way of choosing a "best" one. This is more forum-style than SE-style. It needs to be narrower and more specific to be workable here.

Comment: How do I vote to re-open? This question is already limited in its scope to a very specific themed dinner. I think it's already specific enough.

Comment: @Michael Altfield: I agree with you. There is nothing unfocused about this question. Thanksgiving dinner with relatives is a very common quandary for vegetarians. My wife usually makes vegetable chicken nuggets.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron You can click the "Reopen" button. If it gets some votes, this question will re-open.

Comment: @Michael Altfield: I have searched this page and can not find a "Reopen" Button to click?

Comment: It's next to `Share` and `Flag` links, but you may not have enough points to see it. I see `Share Edit Reopen Delete Flag`