# What can I make for a Passover dinner (vegan)?

Tags: recipe-request

What can I make that's vegan for Passover?

I'm going to a Passover dinner with family. There will be some vegetarians there, but it will mostly be omnivores. What can I make and bring to share with everyone?

I want to make something that will "blend-in" well with traditional Passover dishes (and, of-course, is strictly kosher for Passover), something amazing that I can share with other non-vegetarian attendees to show-off how delicious plant-based meals are, and something that can be filling enough so I'll have plenty to eat -- just in-case there's nothing else there that meets my dietary restrictions..

What's some Passover-style vegan food that I can make this year?

Comment: Pretty much anything that is vegan is strictly kosher, so that's an easy enough requirement... Check with your hosts to see if they have any issues with kitniyot, though, as that will introduce severe limitations.

Comment: Please see [my comment here](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2618/what-can-i-make-for-a-thanksgiving-dinner-vegan?noredirect=1#comment4511_2618) - I'm not going to copy-paste it and make it look like just a boilerplate thing, but the same arguments apply to both questions.

Comment: @therightstuff Unfortunately that's absolutely not true. Not only is passover kosher different from "normal" kosher (for example, you can't eat vegan bread), but also many kosher jews will not buy/consume goods that are not specifically marked as kosher. It's not just about the ingredients, but also the process of preparation and approval from a Rabbi.

Comment: @Randal'Thor How do I vote to re-open? This question is already limited in its scope to a very specific themed dinner. I think it's already specific enough.

Comment: I thought it was obvious that I didn't mean vegan bread or anything else with chametz.